# How to display array of image from firestore in listview flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display of image in listview which read data from firestore. I declare attribure image as array type.Here is my collection.
[image: collection task]

When i run the code, the image only display the first index of array and the second will read the first index of array like this. supposedly the second slide of image, it will display the second index of array from firestore.
[image]
[image]

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:fyp/shared/Loading.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class ListTask extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListTaskState createState() => _ListTaskState();
}


final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserRd(BuildContext context) async* {
  final FirebaseUser rd = await auth.currentUser();
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection("Task").where('uid',isEqualTo: rd.uid).snapshots();
}

class _ListTaskState extends State<ListTask> {
  List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getUserRd(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loading();
            } else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    DocumentSnapshot ba = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    _listOfImages =[];
                    for(int i =0; i < snapshot.data.documents[index].data['url'].length; i++){
                      _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['url'][i]));
                    }
                    return Card(
                        child:ListTile(
                          title: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Sumber Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(ba['sumberAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Nombor Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(ba['noAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Status: ", style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(ba['verified'], style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      height: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white
                                      ),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      child: Carousel(
                                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        images: _listOfImages,
                                        autoplay: false,
                                        indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                                        dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                                        animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                            onTap: () {listAddress(ba['id']);}
                        )
                    );
                  });
              }
           }),
    );
  }
  void listAddress(String id) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0)
            )
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (builder){
          return StreamBuilder(
              stream:Firestore.instance.collection("Task").document(id).snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Loading();
                } else {
                        return Container(
                          height: 150,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 3, 30.0, 5.0),
                            child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                              width: 220,
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:26, left: 14),
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text("Kawasan: ", textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                  Text( snapshot.data['kawasan'], textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              width: 220,
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:4, left: 15),
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text("Nama Jalan :", textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                  Text(snapshot.data['naJalan'], textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              width: 220,
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:4, left: 15),
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text("Kategori : ", textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                  Text(snapshot.data['kategori'], textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                          ),
                          );
                      }
                 }
            );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

can someone explain to me about this problem? is there anything that I missed out? someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. You have exactly the same links in your list `url`, that's why you're getting the same picture.

Comment: but before i upload this picture, i choose 2 different image. how come it just take the first  image only?

Comment: because i using multi_image picker to selected many image

Comment: It's a whole another question :-) Nobody can answer you without seeing the code.

Comment: Take a look at your first screenshot. Can you see that the links are the same?

Comment: yeah I see the link was same. but how came it just only take the first image meanwhile i choose another image which different with the fprevious one. is there anything that i missed out?

Comment: I've no idea what you do in your code which I can't see :-) Make sure you update your image link every time when you're adding a new one.